# if listening to .on('error') and error happens .on('end') doesn't trigger

Tags: node.js, events

So my problem is I'm trying to validate CSV file using node js and [fast-csv](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv)

here is my code so you have a better understanding

```
    csv
  .fromStream(stream, options)
  .on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    currentRow++;
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(err);
    errorLog.push('Error on row ' + currentRow + ' : ' + err);
    res.send(errorLog);
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('end');
    res.send('csv is valid');
  });
```

the problem is if there is an error in any row in the CSV file the on.('error') catches it but the .on('end') never gets triggered.

i need the end event to trigger even if there is an error.

Comment: Why do you want end event to trigger when an error occurred? Is it because you want to send the error message back to the client (which you are already doing with `res.send(errorLog)` )?

Comment: What about `this.emit('end')` inside your error handler? Still I don't see how this is better then wiring up all the clearing logic in some outside function, then calling it both inside `error` and `end`.

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest using this [PR](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv/pull/114) so that errors won't stop the parsing process.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla i want to send all errors to the client cause the CSV file might have more than one error.

Comment: @raina77ow if I use `this.emit('end')` in the error handler it will end the process with the first error which is not what I want. thank you.

Comment: @raina77ow that PR might be what i am looking for thanks I'll check it and come back to you.